# JavaScript Array: Order Nested Object by Key

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, sorting

I have the following nested object. I would like to iterate through every item (latest.sentTime) and then sort the object itself by "sentTime". So that the most recent message is on top. How can I achieve this?

In the following example, "0" and "1" need to be swapped basically, since "1" has a more recent "sentTime".

[image]

Comment: `yourArray.sort(({ latest: { sentTime: a } }, { latest: { sentTime: b } }) => b.localeCompare(a));`.

Answer (score 2):

- Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), iterate over the array to get `latest.sentTime`
- Using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date), sort the items

```js
const arr = [ 
  { latest: { sentTime: '2022-02-05T19:15:32.000Z' } },
  { latest: { sentTime: '2022-02-06T22:12:00.000Z' } } 
];

const sentTimes = arr
  .map(({ latest }) => latest.sentTime)
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(b) - new Date(a));

console.log(sentTimes);
```